# AxesLabel style like in FrameLabel

Tags: plotting

I would like to use `ListPlot` without `Frame`. But `AxesLabel` produces y-label above the y-axis and I want the label to be left from the axis like in `FrameLabel`. How can I get it?

Comment: Why was this closed? The Q is valid, maybe sub-par phrasing. In fact `AxesLabel` butchers `ImageSize` as well, and from the answers so far there's no easy way to get what OP asks.

Answer (score 4):

I've solved this by the following way:

```
ListPlot[list, PlotStyle -> Black, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Arial", Medium], 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"xlabel", "ylabel"}, 
 FrameStyle -> {{None, White}, {None, White}}]
```

Are there another ways?

Comment: You could use `Transparent` instead of `White`.

Answer (score 3):

```
list = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {10, 2}];
```

You can selectively turn the `Frame` elements on/off.

```
ListPlot[list, PlotStyle -> Black, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Arial", Medium],
 Frame -> {{Automatic, None}, {Automatic, None}}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"xlabel", "ylabel"}]
```

[image]

Note that the `Axes` may still appear unless you explicitly turn them off.

```
ListPlot[list, PlotStyle -> Black, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Arial", Medium],
 Axes -> False, Frame -> {{Automatic, None}, {Automatic, None}}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"xlabel", "ylabel"}]
```

[image]